# Guarding critical section in a multithreaded program

Tags: python, multithreading, critical-section

I have a multithreaded Python program (financial trading) in which certain threads execute critical sections (like in the middle of executing a trade). The thread executing the critical sections are daemon threads. The main thread of the program captures `SIGINT` and tries to exit the program gracefully by releasing all resources held by child threads. In order to prevent the main thread causing the child threads to terminate abruptly; the main the thread will loop through the list of child thread objects and call their `shutdown()` function. This function will block till a critical section of the thread completes before returning.

The following is a basic implementation

```
class ChildDaemonThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._critical_section = False        
        # other initialisations

    def shutdown(self):
        # called by parent thread before calling sys.exit(0)

        while True:
            if not self._critical_section:
                break

            # add code to prevent entering critical section
            # do resource deallocation

     def do_critical_stuff(self):
         self._critical_section = True
         # do critical stuff
         self._critical_section = False

     def run(self):
         while True:
             self._do_critical_stuff()
```

I am not sure if my implementation will work because while the `ChildDaemonThread` is executing critical section through `do_critical_stuff()`, if the parent thread calls the child's `shutdown()`, which blocks till a critical section executes, then at this point two methods of the `ChildDaemonThread` `run()` and `do_critical_stuff()` are called at the same time (I am not sure if this is even legal). Is this possible? Is my implementation correct? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some race conditions in this implementation.

You have no guarantee that the main thread will check the value of `_critical_section` at the right time to see a `False` value.  The worker thread may leave and re-enter the critical section before the main thread gets around to checking the value again.  This may not cause any issues of correctness but it could cause your program to take longer to shut down (since when the main thread "misses" a safe time to shut down it will have to wait for another critical section to complete).

Additionally, the worker thread may *re-enter* the critical after the main thread has noticed that `_critical_section` is `False` but before the main thread manages to cause the process to exit.  This could pose real correctness issues since it effectively breaks your attempt to make sure the critical section completes.

Of course, the program may also crash due to some other issue.  Therefore, it may be better if you implement the ability to recover from an interrupted critical section.

However, if you want to improve this strategy to the greatest extent possible, I would suggest something more like this:

```
class ChildDaemonThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self._keep_running = True
        # other initialisations

    def shutdown(self):
        # called by parent thread before calling sys.exit(0)
        self._keep_running = False

     def do_critical_stuff(self):
         # do critical stuff

     def run(self):
         while self._keep_running:
             self._do_critical_stuff()
         # do resource deallocation


workers = [ChildDaemonThread(), ...]

# Install your SIGINT handler which calls shutdown on all of workers
# ...

# Start all the workers
for w in workers:
    w.start()

# Wait for the run method of all the workers to return
for w in workers:
    w.join()
```

The key here is that `join` will block until the thread has finished.  This ensures you're not interrupting one mid-critical-section.

Comment: Hey thank you very much. Your answer makes a lot of sense. I was thinking instead of using a `Boolean` flag `_keep_running` I could you an instance of `Event()` which thread-safe. What's your comment on this?

Comment: I don't _think_ you need `Event` in this case.  Setting an attribute is thread-safe in Python (one thread can do `self._keep_running = False` while another thread reads `self._keep_running`; you can never get an inconsistent result in this case).  It's true that something like `Event` can be useful (and often _necessary_) in certain multi-threading scenarios.  But ... not this one, I think.  I might be wrong.  Reasoning about threading is a challenge.